# Ctrl+. (Dot) makes "e" appear instead of showing suggestions in VSCode on Gnome

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, archlinux, xorg, gnome-shell

I'm using VSCode on Gnome (on XOrg on Arch). Since lately, the shortcut `Ctrl+.` stopped working, despite still being listed in the keyboard shortcuts and despite all extensions being disabled. Instead, an underlined `e` appears:

[image]

The character goes away when pressing enter twice or ESC once. When writing something and then pressing enter, the `e` goes away but the written text stays. When changing the window while the `e` is underlined, it becomes a regular `e`.

This seems to behave somewhat similarly to the compose key, which displays an underlined centered dot after being pressed.

I can't find any keyboard shortcuts for `Ctrl+.` in the Gnome settings.

What is this feature? What is it good for? And how can I restore the original behavior?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is not related to VSCode, as the same thing happens in any text input field across all apps (both on Wayland and Xorg, Fedora).

The issue appeared on my pc when I upgraded to Gnome 42, and I still can't find a way to fix it (keyboard shortcuts don't have any entry for `Ctrl+.`).

Edit: Found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1672408/linux-gnome-how-to-disable-ctrl-shortcut) about this issue. Their fix is to run `ibus-setup` and to disable the ibus shortcut.

Comment: <3 Thanks a lot! Good catch that it happens in all applications. If I had tried that, I would've probably googled more accurately.

Comment: See also [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/v5p8fi/you_can_insert_emoji_quickly_by_pressing_ctrl/) with more discussion

Answer (score 39):

This issue is not related to VSCode. I've experienced it too on my Linux Ubuntu 22.

Try this to turn off Emoji annotation keyboard shortcut:

```
$ gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey "[]"
```

Or run

```
$ ibus-setup
```

Under emoji tab, clear 'Emoji annotation'

[image]

Comment: I'm on Kubuntu 22.04, this fixed the problem. It is a little annoying that the order of checks seems to prioritize ibus over the current application, that is not ideal.

Answer (score 6):

I want to add some details.

1. Command `ibus-setup` opens a window.
2. At the `Emoji` tab you will see `<Control>period;<Control>semicolon`
3. Click three dots on the right-hand side `...`
4. Then select `<Control>period` and delete it. Or change it if you want.
5. Now your `ctrl + .` must be working just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting Gnome solved the issue.
To restart gnome,

1. Press Alt+F2
2. Type r
3. Press Enter

Comment: This only works in Xorg, not in Wayland iirc