# I can't use the shortcut Ctrl + . (dot) on Visual Studio Code on my Linux machine (ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I have a problem on my Linux machine (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS). When using Visual Studio Code I can't use the shortcut Ctrl + . (dot). This shorcut will help me get faster when using Flutter.

Comment: Check keyboard shortcuts if it contains this

Comment: @YeasinSheikh where do i look to check my keyboard shortcuts ?

Comment: See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71997823/9971404).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check keyboard shortcuts if it contains `Ctrl + .`.

[image]

If you can find it, right click on mouse and add or just open json as shown on picture(top-right corner)

and add

```json
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+.",
        "command": "problems.action.showQuickFixes",
        "when": "problemFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+.",
        "command": "editor.action.quickFix",
        "when": "editorHasCodeActionsProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem most likely is that IBus uses that shortcut by default in Ubuntu 22.04 to access emojis. Therefore you need to first change that shortcut by running `ibus-setup` in a terminal, select the *Emoji* tab, and change the *Emoji annotation* shortcut to something else. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1404462/1013434